# how to send data to druid using Tranquility core API?

Tags: druid

I have setup druid and was able to run the tutorial at:[Tutorial: Loading a file](http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-batch.html). I was also able to execute native json queries and get the results as described at : http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-query.html The druid setup is working fine.

I now want to ingest additional data from a Java program into this datasource. Is it possible to send data into druid using tranquility from a java program for a datasource created using batch load?

I tried the example program at : https://github.com/druid-io/tranquility/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/metamx/tranquility/example/JavaExample.java

But this program just keeps running and doesn't show any output. how can druid be setup to accept data using tranquility core APIs?

Following are the ingestion specs and config file for tranquility:

**wikipedia-index.json**

```
{
    "type" : "index",
    "spec" : {
    "dataSchema" : {
       "dataSource" : "wikipedia",
       "parser" : {
       "type" : "string",
    "parseSpec" : {
      "format" : "json",
      "dimensionsSpec" : {
        "dimensions" : [
          "channel",
          "cityName",
          "comment",
          "countryIsoCode",
          "countryName",
          "isAnonymous",
          "isMinor",
          "isNew",
          "isRobot",
          "isUnpatrolled",
          "metroCode",
          "namespace",
          "page",
          "regionIsoCode",
          "regionName",
          "user",
          { "name": "added", "type": "long" },
          { "name": "deleted", "type": "long" },
          { "name": "delta", "type": "long" }
        ]
      },
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "time",
        "format": "iso"
      }
    }
  },
  "metricsSpec" : [],
  "granularitySpec" : {
    "type" : "uniform",
    "segmentGranularity" : "day",
    "queryGranularity" : "none",
    "intervals" : ["2015-09-12/2015-09-13"],
    "rollup" : false
  }
},
"ioConfig" : {
  "type" : "index",
  "firehose" : {
    "type" : "local",
    "baseDir" : "quickstart/",
    "filter" : "wikiticker-2015-09-12-sampled.json.gz"
  },
  "appendToExisting" : false
},
"tuningConfig" : {
  "type" : "index",
  "targetPartitionSize" : 5000000,
  "maxRowsInMemory" : 25000,
  "forceExtendableShardSpecs" : true
}
  }
}
```

**example.json (tranquility config):**

```
{
    "dataSources" : [
      {
        "spec" : {
        "dataSchema" : {
           "dataSource" : "wikipedia",
           "metricsSpec" : [
              { "type" : "count", "name" : "count" }
           ],
           "granularitySpec" : {
              "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
              "queryGranularity" : "none",
              "type" : "uniform"
           },
           "parser" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "parseSpec" : {
                 "format" : "json",
                 "timestampSpec" : {  "column": "time", "format": "iso" },
                 "dimensionsSpec" : {
                    "dimensions" : ["channel",
                                    "cityName",
                                    "comment",
                                    "countryIsoCode",
                                    "countryName",
                                    "isAnonymous",
                                    "isMinor",
                                    "isNew",
                                    "isRobot",
                                    "isUnpatrolled",
                                    "metroCode",
                                    "namespace",
                                    "page",
                                    "regionIsoCode",
                                    "regionName",
                                    "user",
                                    { "name": "added", "type": "long" },
                                    { "name": "deleted", "type": "long" },
                                    { "name": "delta", "type": "long" }]
                 }
              }
           }
        },
        "tuningConfig" : {
           "type" : "realtime",
           "windowPeriod" : "PT10M",
           "intermediatePersistPeriod" : "PT10M",
           "maxRowsInMemory" : "100000"
        }
     },
     "properties" : {
        "task.partitions" : "1",
        "task.replicants" : "1"
     }
  }
    ],
        "properties" : {
       "zookeeper.connect" : "localhost"
   }
}
```

I did not find any example on setting up a datasource on druid which accepts continuously accepts data from a java program. I don't want to use Kafka. Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have yu got something on it? I am also looking at the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the data files with the additional data first and than run the ingestion task with new fields, You can't edit the same record in druid, It overwrites to new record.